# Is it possible to update resources via cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is it feasible to modify resources like redshift cluster via AWS cloudformation template if the resources were created manually and not by AWS cloudformation templates? I want change node type of cluster and modify maintenance window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to import cloudFormation resources using `resource import`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

you still need a valid CloudFormation template